# XOR two lines to see differences

Tags: regular-expression

I need to compute a "XOR"-like of two lines to find every char that differs between the two lines. I know the `vim-diff` feature can easily achieve that, but for comparing two lines I wanted to keep everything in the same buffer.

e.g.

```
1wYT4SH8f8VjRA25u8AItlrTdAY4Y7n-g8if8VjRA3q25u8AItlrTdwTbv8if8VjRA3q25u8AItlrTdJjMY
1wYT4SH8f8VjRA25u8AItlrTdAY4Y7n-g8if8VjRA3q25u8AIt1rTdwTbv8if8VjRA3q25u8AItlrTdJjMY
                                                  1
```

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This solution doesn't show the difference between the two lines but highlight them and allow you to navigate through them with `n` and `N` like this:

[image: Screen cast of the function]

To do so add this function to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! CompareLines(line1, line2)
    let l1 = getline(a:line1)
    let l2 = getline(a:line2)
    let pattern = ""

    for i in range(strlen(l1))
        if strpart(l1, i, 1) != strpart(l2, i, 1)
            if pattern != ""
                let pattern = pattern . "\\|"
            endif
            let pattern = pattern . "\\%" . a:line1 . "l" . "\\%" . ( i+1 ) . "c"
            let pattern = pattern . "\\|" . "\\%" . a:line2 . "l" . "\\%" . ( i+1 ) . "c"
        endif
    endfor

    execute "let @/='" . pattern . "'"
    set hlsearch
    normal n
endfunction
```

You can call the function with `:call CompareLines(1, 2)` where the arguments are the numbers of the lines to compare.

To add a bit more details about how the function works:

- The first lines gets the lines to compare in some variables.
- The loop iterates through these strings. Each characters of the strings are compared and when they don't match a pattern of the form `\%Xl\%Yc` is added to the variable `pattern` where `X` and `Y` are the line and the column of a character.

  (See [`:h /ordinary-atom`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/ordinary-atom) and especially the last lines which explains that the pattern `\%23l` allows to match the 23rd line and `\%23c` the 23rd column)
- Once the pattern is build it is injected in the search register (`let @/=` allow to define the content of the register and the pattern has to be quoted).
- Finally `set hlsearch` is used to highlight all the matches of the pattern and `normal n` brings the cursor to the first different character.

**Note 1** The function will change your search history.

**Note 2** The part which uses the pattern to make the search could probably be greatly improved.

**And as a bonus** Add this line to your `.vimrc` to create a command which will faster the call of the function:

```
command! -nargs=* CompLines call CompareLines(<f-args>)
```

This way you can simple use `:CompLines 1 2` to compares two lines.

---

**EDIT** And here is an improved version of the function and of the command. The difference is that you can call it in 3 different ways:

- `:CL` will diff the current line and the following one
- `:CL 23` will diff the current line and the line 23
- `:CL 23 42` will diff the lines 23 and 42

Here is the code:

```
command! -nargs=* CL call CompareLines(<f-args>)

function! CompareLines(...)

    " Check the number of arguments
    " And get lines numbers
    if len(a:000) == 0
        let l1=line(".")
        let l2=line(".")+1
    elseif len(a:000) == 1
        let l1 =line(".")
        let l2 =a:1
    elseif len(a:000) == 2
        let l1 = a:1
        let l2 = a:2
    else
        echom "bad number of arguments"
        return;
    endif

    " Get the content of the lines
    let line1 = getline(l1)
    let line2 = getline(l2)

    let pattern = ""

    " Compare lines and create pattern of diff
    for i in range(strlen(line1))
        if strpart(line1, i, 1) != strpart(line2, i, 1)
            if pattern != ""
                let pattern = pattern . "\\|"
            endif
            let pattern = pattern . "\\%" . l1 . "l" . "\\%" . ( i+1 ) . "c"
            let pattern = pattern . "\\|" . "\\%" . l2 . "l" . "\\%" . ( i+1 ) . "c"
        endif
    endfor

    " Search and highlight the diff
    execute "let @/='" . pattern . "'"
    set hlsearch
    normal n
endfunction
```

---

**EDIT 2** I made it [a plugin](http://github.com/statox/vim-compare-lines). You can install it with a regular plugin manager with (e.g.):

```
Plug 'statox/vim-compare-lines'
```